# Serpent IP Начальная перестановка

Tags: криптография

Пожалуйста, подскажите правильно ли я понимаю таблицу начальной перестановки IP в шифровании Serpent. Т.к. она используется при получение раундовых ключей, а каждый ключ `K0={w0,w1,w2,w3}` w0 размер 32 байта, но таблица IP имеет 128 значений, значит, нужно склеить 4 ключа, чтобы получить 128-битный ключ. Далее каждый бит 128-битного ключа переходит на соответствующую ячейку. Например, `K0={0xBBBBBBBB,0xBBBBBBBB,0xBBBBBBBB,0xBBBBBBBB}` переведем все в bin

```
10111011101110111011101110111011,10111011101110111011101110111011,10111011101110111011101110111011,10111011101110111011101110111011
```

Первые 5 значений в IP это 0, 32, 64, 96, 1, значит нулевой бит перейдет на нулевую позицию, 32 бит - на первую, 64 - на вторую, 96 - на третью, 1 бит - на четвертую.
Значит: 11110 и так далее. Иными словами, просто берем позицию согласно таблице IP в склеенной 128 битной строке и перенесем на новую позицию. Во всяком случае так происходит в DES. Но все же в Serpent, по-моему, IP/Inv IP работает не так.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Rrace8](/users/23319/rrace8)](/users/23319/rrace8), зачем вы пытаетесь самостоятельно реализовать пермутации Serpent'а?

Во-первых, это довольно муторное занятие, а во-вторых, во многом бессмысленное. Имеются референсные (образцовые) реализации Serpent - погуглите или просто [ткните сюда](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/serpent.html).

Битовые пермутации обычно довольно сложны в реализации, и ими занимаются сами криптографы.

Comment: Просто на Википедии дана таблица IP, и сказанно, что '32-й бит перейдет на 1-ю позицию', я и подумал, что мы делаем IP, как в DES. Получается, тот пример, что я привел, неправильный, и IP проводить так нельзя?